# Should I be concerned about a very slow leak in a patched tire?

Tags: tires

Brand new tires, within a couple weeks after purchase I ran over a screw, and had to get one tire patched.

Now, after the patch, the tire loses about 4 psi per week. It's a very slow leak and I've just been topping it off every Monday.

Could the patch be a bit leaky? Is that normal? Should I have the tire patched again? Spraying soapy water has not identified anything obvious.

Comment: Just a follow-up. I had the tire re-patched and it's held up just fine for a year now, stopped the slow leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would get it patched if for no other reason than to ensure it stays up. When the tire gets low and you drive on it, there is extra heat which is generated through the tire. This can lead to premature tire failure. If you forget to do it for a couple extra days, then it might be 6psi low, or something greater. This would lead to greater heat and tire wear, as well as putting your vehicle, yourself, and your passengers at risk, let alone the people driving around you. For piece of mind, get the tire fixed *correctly*.

Comment: We explain it to my customers at my shop like this; "Tires can be expected to blow out, with low pressure and high speed." Get that tire fixed thousands of parts make up a vehicle only 4 touch the road. The leak shows you the tire is not working/performing the way its supposed to. Safety first.

Comment: @BrandonEtsinger - Nice. Succinct. Absolutely on-point!